# How does the "ZPH" option of PROC PHREG in SAS 9.4 works?

Tags: survival, cox-model, sas

As I saw in [SAS 9.4 documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/zh-CN/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/statug/statug_phreg_syntax01.htm), the "ZPH" option in `PROC PHREG` statement requests diagnostics based on the weighted Schoenfeld residuals for checking the proportional hazards assumption. Then I used it like this:

```
proc phreg data=mydata zph(transform=rank);
    class group(ref="Placebo");
    model time*status(0) = group wbc;
run;
```

In addition to Time-Varying Coefficient Plots, SAS gives zph test results as following:

[image]

Also, I am aware of another Goodness-of-Fit approach to test the PH assumption:

1. Run Cox PH model and obtain Schoenfeld residuals for each predictor.
2. Create a variable that ranks the order of failures.
3. Test the correlation between the variables created in the first and second steps.

And I really think they are the same approach, conducting the same test results. So I tried:

```
proc phreg data=mydata;
    class group(ref="Placebo");
    model time*status(0) = group wbc;
    output out=resid ressch=r_group r_wbc;
    /* ressch option calculates Schoenfeld residuals for each predictor */
run;

proc rank data=resid(where=(status=1)) out=ranked ties=mean;
    var time;
    ranks t_rank;
run;

proc corr data=ranked nosimple;
    var r_group r_wbc;
    with t_rank;
run;
```

which gives obviously different estimations of correlation and p-value:

[image]

So, what's the key point leading to these difference? If these two are different methods, then which one to choose when evaluating the PH assumption?

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: As you already indicated these are based on the *weighted* Schoenfeld residuals (you probably want `WTRESSCH=` in your output statement). See [here](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/zh-CN/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/statug/statug_phreg_details53.htm#statug.phreg.phregdetailszph) for more details.

Comment: Comment from @PBulls is helpful. Just use `wtressch=` option rather than `ressch=` will finally eliminate the discrepancy.